# Как сделать так же как в dle[CLOSED]

Tags: jquery, ajax, php

Здравствуйте уважаемый! Хотелось бы узнать у вас как сделать так же как dle реализовано обращения к каким либо значения через свои спецификаторы например такие как {title} и другие....подскажите литературу пожалуйста!Спасибо!

Comment: просто интересно как они через свои скажем так "теги" обращаются к данным....простите я не просвещен в данном вопросе..простите если что...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.define.php